# After update Symfony throws weird errors

Tags: symfony

Today i decided to downlaod the FOS user-bundle, i used the following command "composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev"" everything was downloaded, so I went to my website and there is this error:

```
Attempted to load class "MonologBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I have the bundle in the vendor folder, tried with cleaning the cache, still same. Any thoughts?

Stack:

```
in AppKernel.php line 14
at AppKernel->registerBundles() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2565
at Kernel->initializeBundles() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2394
at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2426
at Kernel->handle() in app_dev.php line 28
at {main}() in app_dev.php line 0
```

Comment: Did you register the new bundle(s) in the kernel?

Comment: Yes i did - error, then i removed it - still error

Comment: And did you also add the monolog bundle to the kernel?

Comment: No, it's default installed by symfony.

Comment: I must say, I am a bit confused that this happens after you install FOSUserBundle as that does not have a dependency on monolog at all. Have you tried removing FOSUserBundle again and checked whether the problem goes away?

Comment: Yes i have, also tried to remove it and install it again(both FOSUserBundle and Monolog)

Comment: So did the problem go away when you removed those bundles? Also please submit a more complete error message. I assume there is a stack trace that comes with it?

Comment: When i removed the use statement from AppKernel, error changed to next in line(SwiftMailer), StackTrace Added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in composer.json, monolog wasn't included and so it wasn't autoloaded.

Solution: Download composer.json from https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard